# Doctrine extensions (Gedmo) Translatable - how display translated entity based on current locale

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm, zend-translate

I have the gedmo translatable extension  working in my zend framework application. I mean that the following code creates the ext_translations table and inserts the translated articles in the table.

```
$article = new \App\Entity\Article;
$article->setTitle('my title in en');
$article->setContent('my content in en');
$this->_em->persist($article);
$this->_em->flush();

//// first load the article
$article = $this->_em->find('App\Entity\Article', 1 /*article id*/);
$article->setTitle('my title in de');
$article->setContent('my content in de');
$article->setTranslatableLocale('de_de'); // change locale
$this->_em->persist($article);
$this->_em->flush();

// first load the article
$article = $this->_em->find('App\Entity\Article', 1 /*article id*/);
$article->setTitle('my title in es');
$article->setContent('my content in es');
$article->setTranslatableLocale('es_es'); // change locale
$this->_em->persist($article);
$this->_em->flush();

$article = $this->_em->getRepository('App\Entity\Article')->find(1/* id of article */);
echo $article->getTitle();
// prints: "my title in en"
echo $article->getContent();
// prints: "my content in en"
```

The above works and prints what I have included in the comments. However, if I change my application locale to es_ES it gives the same output and doesn't seem to notice the change in locale.

In my bootstrap, it is set up as follow :

```
public function _initLocale() {
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myswaplocalesession');
        if ($session->locale) {
            $locale = new Zend_Locale($session->locale);
        }

        $config = $this->getOptions();

        if (!isset($locale) || $locale === null) {
            try {
                $locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
            } catch (Zend_Locale_Exception $e) {
                $locale = new Zend_Locale($config['resources']['locale']['default']);
            }

        }
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

        echo $locale;

        $translator = new Zend_Translate('gettext', APPLICATION_PATH . '/../data/lang/',
                        null, array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME, 'disableNotices' => 1));


        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translator);
        Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You must tell to Gedmo what locale, by default, must use.

You can add these lines when you know what locale to use:

```
$listener = $this->getDoctrine()->getEventManager()->getListener(
    'Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener'
);

$listener->setTranslatableLocale($locale);
```

Comment: Hi, I like the idea but get this error:'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Invalid method "getDoctrine"' in /var/www/testsite/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 605'

Comment: After considerable messing around I managed to get an instance of the eventmanager in the bootstrap (see one of my other questions for details), but the translatable listener is not available in the bootstrap either as it hasn't been initialized yet. I think there must be another method that doesn't involve getting so bogged down in the bootstrap. Can translatable not get the locale value from registry later?